# 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, Input to reshape is a tensor with 6144 values, but the requested shape has 3072

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created TFrecord file with mfccs of music segment and theirs labels. But I am running into a problem of tenor shape. I'm sure that the shape of mfcc is [256,12] before writing to TFrecord file. It seems that the requested shape is half of the tensor read from the file. I can't locate the mistake and don't know the reason. Could you please give me some advice? thanks

```
enter code here
def read_tfRecord(file_tfRecord):
queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file_tfRecord])
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_,serialized_example = reader.read(queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,features={'micsegment': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)})
mic=tf.decode_raw(features['micsegment'],tf.float32)
mic=tf.reshape(mic,[256,12,1])
label=tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int64)
return mic,label

[mic,label]=read_tfRecord('D:/360MoveData/training.tfrecords')  
[testmic,testlabel]=read_tfRecord('D:/360MoveData/test1.tfrecords')

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [256*12]) 
y_actual = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)  


def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool(x,ksize):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize,strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

x_mic=tf.reshape(x,[-1,256,12,1]) 

W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 16])      
b_conv1 = bias_variable([16])       
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_mic, W_conv1) + b_conv1)     #第一个卷积层
h_pool1 = max_pool(h_conv1,ksize=[1,2,2,1]) 

W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 16, 32])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)      
h_pool2 = max_pool(h_conv2,ksize=[1,2,3,1])


W_conv3 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 32])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)      
h_pool3 = max_pool(h_conv3,ksize=[1,2,2,1])

W_fc1 = weight_variable([32*1*32, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool3, [-1, 32*1*32])             
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)    

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float") 
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)                  

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
y_predict=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)   #softmax




cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_predict* tf.log(y_actual), reduction_indices=[1]))  
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)   
correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_predict, y_actual)    
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)) 


sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# start the threads used for reading files
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)

# start training
nSteps=1000
for i in range(nSteps):

  batch_xs, batch_ys=sess.run([mic_batches,label_batches])

 # run the training step with feed of images

  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_actual: batch_ys, keep_prob: 0.5})


  if (i+1)%100==0: # then perform validation 

  # get a validation batch
    vbatch_xs, vbatch_ys = sess.run([mictest_batches,labeltest_batches])
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:vbatch_xs, y_actual: vbatch_ys, keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i+1, train_accuracy))


# finalise 
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)  
sess.close()
```

and this is my code for compute mfccs and write Tfrecord file

```
enter code here
def load_file(example_list_file):
 lines = np.genfromtxt(example_list_file,delimiter="*",dtype=[('col1','S200'), ('col2', 'i8')])
 examples = []
 labels = []
 for example,label in lines:
 examples.append(example)
 labels.append(label)
return np.asarray(examples),np.asarray(labels),len(lines)

enter code here
_examples,_labels,examples_num = load_file(train_file)
filename = name + '.tfrecords'
writer= tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
for i,[example,label] in enumerate(zip(_examples,_labels)):
  micseg = compute_spectrograms(example)
  micsegment=micseg.tostring()
  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={ 'micsegment':_bytes_feature(micsegment), 'label': _int64_feature(label)}))
  writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```